# Let $75!$ be in base of $10$ , then what is the last two digits of it in the base of $3$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

When I get around at park , I made up a question to hang out by myself.However , I stuck in it.

Question: Let $75!$ be in base of $10$ , then what is the last two digits of it in the base of $3$?

Where I stuck in :

$1-)$ I know how to write $75$ in the base of $3$ , but I do not know writing $75!$ in the base of $3$.

$2-)$ To find the last two digits, we utilize from $(\text{mod }100)$, then which modulus should I use to find its last two digits?

Thanks for your helps..

Comment: hint:  what is $9_{10}$ in base $3$?

Comment: Probably you meant that $75$ is a number in the base $10$.

Comment: @user nope , i meant $75!$ (seventy five factorial)

Comment: But it does not matter for your question how $75!$ is represented in the base 10. It only matter what do you mean by "75".

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:* $75!$ is a multiple of $3^2$.

More generally, the number of trailing zeros in the representation of $n!$ in base $3$ is
$$
f(n)=\sum _{{i=1}}^{\infty}\left\lfloor {\frac  {n}{3^{i}}}\right\rfloor 
$$
but note that there are only finitely many nonzero terms.

So, $75!$ has $35$ trailing zeros in base $3$.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trailing_zero#Factorial

Answer (score 2):

Since $75!= 1\times 2\times \dots \times 9 \times \dots \times 75$, it is divisible by $9$, which means that it can be written as $$75!= 3^2(a_0 + 3a_1 +3^2a_2 +\dots +3^n a_n) =3^2 a_0 +3^3a_1 +3^4 a_2 +\dots+3^{n+2}a_n\\ =(a_n \dots a_2 \ a_1 a_0 \ 0\ 0)_3 $$

Answer (score 0):

You can answer with *Legendre's formula* and calculate the $3$-valuation of $75!$:
$$ v_3(75!)=\biggl\lfloor\frac{75}3\biggr\rfloor+\biggl\lfloor\frac{75}9\biggr\rfloor + \biggl\lfloor\frac{75}{27}\biggr\rfloor=25+8+2=35,$$
so you know that, in bases $3$, the last $\mathbf{35}$ digits will be $0$.